# Pad with leading zeros

Tags: c#

How can i pad my integer variable with leading zeros.
like i have an integer abc with value 20 but i want it to be '0000020'.

Code:

```
quarterlyReportDataCMMS.QRTrailerRecord.FileRecordCount = Convert.ToInt32(refEligibleClaimants.Count);
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can do this with a string datatype. Use the `PadLeft` method:

```
var myString = "1";
myString = myString.PadLeft(myString.Length + 5, '0');
```

> 000001

Comment: Alternatively, if you wanted fixed number of places where 5 is the total number of placed replaced with 0:

myString.PadLeft(5, '0')

Comment: Although this answer is useful, it's not the way to do it unless you're starting out with a string.

Answer (score 160):

There's no such concept as an integer with padding. How many legs do you have - 2, 02 or 002? They're the same number. Indeed, even the "2" part isn't really part of the number, it's only relevant in the decimal representation.

If you need padding, that suggests you're talking about the *textual representation* of a number... i.e. a string.

You can achieve that using string formatting options, e.g.

```
string text = value.ToString("0000000");
```

or

```
string text = value.ToString("D7");
```

Comment: I tried that but it says Cannot implicitly convert type string to int

Comment: @Ashutosh: No, the point is you *want* it as a string. There's no such concept as a padded int - an int is *just a number*.

Comment: @Jon but your code is trying to implicitly convert a string to an int... (`int text = value.ToString("000")`)

Comment: @Steven: Doh - will fix that. I'm a fool! Apologies to @Ashutosh and anyone else who tried this. I'll hang my head in shame :(

Comment: @Jon: No problem John..I fixed it somehow. I am a novice in this field who fortunately got an internship, so i am learning all these things to fulfill the expectations.
thanks

Comment: @TomGullen plus it is a code **name** it's entirely the fault of the naming convention :P

Answer (score 20):

An integer value is a mathematical representation of a number and is ignorant of leading zeroes.

You can get a *string* with leading zeroes like this:

```
someNumber.ToString("00000000")
```

Answer (score 15):

The concept of leading zero is meaningless for an int, which is what you have.  It is only meaningful, when printed out or otherwise rendered as a string.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0000000}", FileRecordCount);
```

Forgot to end the double quotes!

Answer (score 15):

You can use

[String.PadLeft()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft.aspx)
[String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)