# How get the count of an array? inC#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

```
char[] charArray = startno.ToCharArray();
//using this arry
//i want to cheque this 

int i=0;
count = 0;
while (chenum [i] != "0")
     {
         count++;
         i++;
     }
     string s = "0";
     string zero = "0";
     for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)
     {
         s = s + zero;
     }
```

will u help me to correct this code...
eg:(00001101) i need to add this no with 1.
for that i want to convert this value to int.if i convert to int the no will be(1101)+1 no will be (1102).after adding i want the answer (00001102).

Answer (score 6):

how many zeros do you want?? You can use string.pad

```
int count = 1102;
            int NumOfZeros = 10;
            string s = count.ToString().PadLeft(NumOfZeros, '0');
```

there is also the number formatter.

```
count.ToString("D10");
```

Comment: PadLeft is pretty slick. I had never noticed it. I always used the string formatter. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are storing this number as an int (and you should) 1102 annd 00001102 are the same thing. Use string formatting later when you need to output the value with some zeros.

`1102.ToString("D8")` will give you the string `"00001102"`

Also, possible duplicates of this question: [Pad with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459610/pad-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: i want to store it in data base as 00001102

Comment: @RAHUL: is it meant to be used as a number or as a string?

Answer (score 2):

```
String num = "000001101";
int item = int.Parse(num);
item++;
String output = item.ToString("D8");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `String.Format("{0:00000000}", 1101);`, which would be 00001101

Answer (score 1):

Try `int.parseInt(startNo)` instead of converting it to a `char` array.