# Padding value in the QueryString

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, query-string

I have a QS like this:

```
Request.QueryString = Id=443f0cb9&Num=9232323
```

Now I want to add 000 in front of Num. Like this: 0009232323

How would I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459610/pad-with-leading-zeros

Comment: How are you constructing the query string?

Comment: through JS. But this one I am doing for cross browser issues only. In IE7 the stuff is not working. All other browsers its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QueryString property of the HttpRequest is a NameValueCollection you would need append the "000" to the item in the collection. I've used the PedLeft from the question linkedby @Davide Paris

```
if (Request.QueryString["Num"] != null)
{
    string num = Request.QueryString["Num"];
    Request.QueryString["Num"] = num.PadLeft((num.Length + 3), '0');
}
```