# Mask to format int 1, 10, 100, to string "001", "010", "100"

Tags: c#

How do I apply a mask to a string aiming to format the output text in the following fashion (at most 2 leading zeros):

```
int a = 1, b = 10, c = 100;
string aF = LeadingZeroFormat(a), bF = LeadingZeroFormat(b), cF = LeadingZeroFormat(c);
Console.Writeline("{0}, {1}, {2}", aF, bF, cF); // "001, 010, 100"
```

What is the most elegant solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122677/add-zero-padding-to-a-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pad with leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459610/pad-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use Int32.ToString("000") to format an integer in this manner.  For details, see [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) and [Int32.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y):

```
string one = a.ToString("000"); // 001
string two = b.ToString("000"); // 010
```

Answer (score 17):

As well as Reed's suggestion, you can do it directly in your compound format string:

```
int a = 1, b = 10, c = 100;
Console.WriteLine("{0:000}, {1:000}, {2:000}", a, b, c); // "001, 010, 100"
```

Answer (score 3):

> To display the integer as a decimal value, call its ToString(String)
>   method, and pass the string "Dn" as the value of the format parameter,
>   where n represents the minimum length of the string.

```
int i = 10;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("D3"));
```

Also check [How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)