# Simple and elegant way to zero-pad a value in C#

Tags: c#, zero-pad

I have to fix malformed zipcodes. The people who exported the data treated the zipcode as a numeric and as a result New Jersey and Puerto Rico zipcodes, which begin with a leading zero and two leading zeroes respectively, have been truncated.

They're supposed to be all five characters (no zip+4 data is involved).  I know how to zero-pad brute-force by getting the length and prepending the appropriate number of zeroes to the string, but is there a more elegant  way that draws on the "native" features of C#? For example, can a mask be applied that would turn "9163" into "09163" and "904" into "00904" without my having to get the length of the value?

Comment: BTW: must be a duplicate several times over....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122677/add-zero-padding-to-a-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459610/pad-with-leading-zeros, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901395/pad-left-with-zeroes, etc.. you'd really hope an admin would search first! ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an integer value, use the composite format string to ensure padding:

```
var padded1 = 1.ToString("D5");
```

The number after `D` is for the length you need the value to be in.

Comment: Thank you, it works when the original string value was truncated and turned into a numeric, as in my scenario.

Answer (score 10):

```
string test = "9163";
test = test.PadLeft (5, '0');
```

Comment: `string paddedString = test.PadLeft (5, '0');`

Comment: Thank you, it works when the truncated value is a string.

Answer (score 3):

```
  string s = string.Format("{0:00000}", 1234);

  Console.WriteLine(s);
```

[Format String Reference](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

Comment: Thank you for the string-mask approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
string one = a.ToString("00000"); // 00904
```

Comment: Thank you, easiest for me to remember.